# "import" sys command not found

Tags: pi-3, python

I'm trying to solve a bash error when configuring a DHT11 sensor on Raspberry Pi 3.
Trying to set up the Pi to connect to an SSH Terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys *(problem starts here. see below error)*
import Adafruit_DHT

while True:

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)

    print 'Temp: {0:0.1f} C  Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
```

#### Error:

```
bash: import: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you running this script?

The error is telling me it's being interpreted as `bash`, so my guess is:

```
bash script.py
```

You've posted a pretty good question, but try to give a bit more detail, especially the exact command you're running when you have the issue.

If you were to change that to the following, it would work:

```
python script.py
```

Otherwise, are you just copy and pasting that into your `bash` terminal?  In that case, you need to create a file named something like `script.py`, put the script in there, save it, and then execute the file.

However, the *entire point* of your shebang/top line is to tell the system which interpreter to use, so you should give execution permission to your script, and run it as so:

```
chmod +x script.py
./script.py
```

This way, your system will read the first line, and use `python`.  While you're at it, you should change your shebang to read:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```